# 10x10 Matrix Generation with user selection: Getting sum and average per row and column of matrix

Tags: c, matrix, sum, row, calculated-columns

we were given a problem to generate a matrix with different options to choose from. Among them were getting the sum and average per row and column of the matrix (Option A & B). I seem not to get the sum per rows and column. Can anyone help me. Thanks!

[Portion of the problem: Option A & B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRBAq.png)

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void printOptions() {
    printf("\nOptions\n");
    printf("a: Total sum, average, median per row\n");
    printf("b: Total sum, average, median per column\n");
    printf("c: Display the same matrix but all ODD numbers are replaced with '-'\n");
    printf("d: Display the same matrix but all EVEN numbers are replaced with '+'\n");
    printf("e: Display the same matrix but all PRIME numbers are replaced with '*'\n");
    printf("f: Display the whole matrix with every row in ascending order\n");
    printf("g: Display the whole matrix with every row in descending order\n");
    printf("h: Display the whole matrix with every column in ascending order\n");
    printf("i: Display the whole matrix with every column in descending order\n");
    printf("j: Generate new set of random numbers\n");
    printf("q: Close the program\n");
    printf("\n");
}

// function to swap the elements
void swapEl(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

// function to check if the given number is a prime number
int isPrime(int x) {
    for(int i = 2; i < x; i++) {
        if(x % i == 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// function to sort the array
int *Sortarr(int given[], int n)
{
    int *arr = given;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                swapEl(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    int N = 10;
    int matrix[N][N];
    int tot_sum;
    double median_r[N], median_c[N], sum_r[N], sum_c[N];

    printf("\nMatrix:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            //print
            if(matrix[i][j] < N && matrix[i][j] > 0)
            {

                printf("%d \t",matrix[i][j]);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d \t",matrix[i][j]);
            }

        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    int sorted_r[N][N], sorted_c[N][N];

    // sum per row
    for(int i =0; i < N; i++){
        tot_sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            tot_sum += matrix[i][j];
            sum_r[j] = matrix[i][j];
        }

    }
    // sum per column
    for(int j =0; j < N; j++){
        tot_sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            tot_sum += matrix[i][j];
            sum_c[j] = matrix[i][j];
        }

    }

    // median per row
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int temparr[N];
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) temparr[j] = matrix[i][j];
        int *sorted = Sortarr(temparr, N);
        median_r[i] = (sorted[N / 2] + sorted[N / 2 - 1]) / 2.0;
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) sorted_r[i][j] = sorted[j];
    }

    // median per column
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int temparr[N];
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) temparr[j] = matrix[j][i];
        int *sorted = Sortarr(temparr, N);
        median_c[i] = (sorted[N / 2] + sorted[N / 2 - 1]) / 2.0;
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) sorted_c[j][i] = sorted[j];
    }

    int ch = 0;

    while(ch != 1) {

        printOptions();
        char userChoice;
        printf("Select an option ('x'): ");
        userChoice = getc(stdin);
        getchar();


        switch(userChoice) {
            case 'a':

                for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    printf("Sum for row %d : %f\t", i + 1, sum_r[i]);
                    printf("Average for row %d : %f\t", i + 1, sum_r[i]/10);
                    printf("Median for row %d : %f\n", i + 1, median_r[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 'b':
                for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    printf("Sum for column %d : %f\t", j + 1, sum_c[j]);
                    printf("Average for column %d : %f\t", j + 1, sum_c[j]/10);
                    printf("Median for column %d : %f\n", j + 1, median_c[j]);
                }
                break;
            case 'c':
                for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                        if(matrix[i][j] % 2 == 1) printf("- ");
                        else printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'd':
                for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                        if(matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0) printf("+ ");
                        else printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'e':
                for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                        if(isPrime(matrix[i][j]) == 1) printf("* ");
                        else printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'f':
                for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                        printf("%d ", sorted_r[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'g':
                for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    for(int j = N - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                        printf("%d ", sorted_r[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'h':
                for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                        printf("%d ", sorted_c[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'i':
                for(int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                        printf("%d ", sorted_c[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            case 'j':
                tot_sum = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                        matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
                        tot_sum += matrix[i][j];
                        printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }

                break;
            case 'q':
                ch = 1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        printf("\n");

    }

}
```

Comment: `sum_r[j] = matrix[i][j];` would make more sense after the `j` loop with `sum_r[j] = tot_sum;`

Comment: Note: `isPrime(int x)` gives wrong answer for `x <= 1` and is _slow_.

Comment: In general, I suggest using many more specialized functions versus cramming everything into `main`. Things like `generateMatrix`, `printMatrix`, `sumRow`, `sumColumn`, `medianOfRow` ... etc.

Comment: @chux Actually, `sum_r[i] = tot_sum;` :-) (But `sum_c[j] = tot_sum;`.)